# extract a column based on other two column

Tags: r

```
ID  MON in  out
2   1   23  12
3   1   23  12
7   1   33  22
1   2   22  11
2   2   111 100
1   3   21  10
2   3   22  11
2   4   111 100
7   4   21  10
2   5   31  20
7 2046  41  30
```

I have a large data set in this format. I want to extract column four for the value of column 1==2 and column 2 smaller then 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basic R.

```
df[,4][df[,1]==2 & df[,2]<5]
```